# Changing CSS with jquery works with .parent().addClass but not just .addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

See edit below. The question originated while I had very poor jquery/javascript for my validation. I have since implemented a new css class that should be taking care of what the individual element edits were doing previously. As well, my jquery validation is much more dynamic and for more than just empty fields.

---

I have been working on a web portal based on the python web framework cherrypy, and I have recently been working on improving the user input validation on the different forms within the related jquery.

Originally, my jquery was doing one large check if any inputs did not meet the validation requirements and then changing the border of the input fields and the input labels to red. It has since been improved to now do an individual check for each required field and then information about that field is appended to the error message that will be rendered after the full validation has been completed. As well, only the fields which are not validated have the input fields borders and labels changed to red instead of all required fields like before.

What I am looking to do now for my next improvement was to update my jquery to hopefully reset the css back to the base before doing the validation check. This is to make it so that fields which may have been corrected by the user will not remain altered with the red input field border and input label. But since it is doing the validation once again as it is going through the submit process any fields which are unable to be validated will be altered again to show the red highlighting.

Is there anything I can do besides having many of these at the beginning of the submit function?

```
document.getElementById('elementHere').style.borderColor = "black";
document.getElementById('elementHere').style.color = "black";
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //snip

  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $("#dlgmessage").html("Processing...");
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
        
        //New Validation
        var validated = "yes";
        var msg = "One or more fields do not meet the validation requirements:<ul>";
        if (
            Clean($("#txtIndex").val()) === ""
        ) {
            document.getElementById('txtIndex').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById('txtIndex_label').style.color = "red";
            validated = "no";
            msg = msg + "<li>Index is required</li>";
        }
        if (
            Clean($("#txtSourcetype").val()) === ""
        ) {
            document.getElementById('txtSourcetype').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById('txtSourcetype_label').style.color = "red";
            validated = "no";
            msg = msg + "<li>Sourcetype is required</li>";
        }
        if (
            Clean($("#txtUseCase").val()) === ""
        ) {
            document.getElementById('txtUseCase').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById('txtUseCase_label').style.color = "red";
            validated = "no";
            msg = msg + "<li>Use Case is required</li>";
        }
        if (
            Clean($("#txtTechOwner").val()) === ""
        ) {
            document.getElementById('txtTechOwner').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById('txtTechOwner_label').style.color = "red";
            validated = "no";
            msg = msg + "<li>Technical Owner is required</li>";
        }
        if (
            Clean($("#txtExecOwner").val()) === ""
        ) {
            document.getElementById('txtExecOwner').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById('txtExecOwner_label').style.color = "red";
            validated = "no";
            msg = msg + "<li>Execuitve Owner is required</li>";
        }
        if (
            Clean($("#txtAllocation").val()) === ""
        ) {
            document.getElementById('txtAllocation').style.borderColor = "red";
            document.getElementById('txtAllocation_label').style.color = "red";
            validated = "no";
            msg = msg + "<li>Allocation is required</li>";
        }
        if (
            validated == "no"
        ) {
            msg = msg + "</ul>";
            $( "#dlgmessage" ).html(msg);
            $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog("open");
            console.log("Missing Required Fields");
            document.getElementById('instructions').style.color = "red";
            return;
        }
      
        //Make sure basic inputs are filled in
        //if (
        //    Clean($("#txtIndex").val()) === "" ||
        //    Clean($("#txtSourcetype").val()) === "" ||
        //    Clean($("#txtUseCase").val()) === "" ||
        //    Clean($("#txtTechOwner").val()) === "" ||
        //    Clean($("#txtExecOwner").val()) === "" ||
        //    Clean($("#txtAllocation").val()) === "" 
        //){
        //    $("#dlgmessage").html("Please fill in required fields (*)");
        //    $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
        //    document.getElementById('txtIndex').style.borderColor = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtIndex_label').style.color = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtSourcetype').style.borderColor = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtSourcetype_label').style.color = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtUseCase').style.borderColor = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtUseCase_label').style.color = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtTechOwner').style.borderColor = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtTechOwner_label').style.color = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtExecOwner').style.borderColor = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtExecOwner_label').style.color = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtAllocation').style.borderColor = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('txtAllocation_label').style.color = "red";
        //    document.getElementById('instructions').style.color = "red";
        //    console.log("Missing Required Fields");
        //    
        //    return;
        //}
        
      
        // validation passed
        var postdata = {
            record_id: Clean($("#txtID").val()),
            splunk_index: Clean($("#txtIndex").val()),
            splunk_sourcetype: Clean($("#txtSourcetype").val()),
            use_case: Clean($("#txtUseCase").val()),
            tech_owner: Clean($("#txtTechOwner").val()),
            exec_owner: Clean($("#txtExecOwner").val()),
            allocation: Clean($("#txtAllocation").val()),
            comments: Clean($("#txtComments").val()),
            action: "Add/Update",
            page_name:location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
            } ;
       
      
        $.post( "/submit", {data:JSON.stringify(postdata)},
            function( data ) {
                var msg = data;
                console.log(msg);
                $("#dlgmessage").html(msg);
                $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
                if (
                    msg == "Database Update Successful" ||
                    msg == "Database Submission Successful"
                ) {
                    $(location).attr('href', '/protected/ci_sourcetype_usecase_list.html');
                }
                //return false;
            },
            'text'
        );
      
     
    });
});
```

I am hoping there is some way that the css can just be 'reset' but if I just need to explicitly state each element and what color to go back to that is okay.

---

**EDIT:**

Okay, I realized that my code before was very basic and probably not ideal, I have spent some time working through improving my jquery to be more dynamic and not require a shitload of if statements written out with every condition. I believe I have everything coming together well but right now I can see my classes added to each of my html elements I wanted, however no style is being applied and the labels and inputs stay normal instead of turning red as I expected. It was working when I did it earlier with `$(field_id).parent().addClass("error");` but I wanted to only have the invalidated fields marked in red.

Find my updated code below

Thanks

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {  
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $("#dlgmessage").html("Processing...");
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
        //console.log("btnSubmit()");

        var postdata = {
            splunk_host: Clean($("#txtSplunkHost").val()),
            ip: Clean($("#txtIP").val()),
            mgmt_ip: Clean($("#txtMgmtIP").val()),
            splunk_role: Clean($("#txtRole").val()),
            environment: Clean($("#txtEnvironment").val()),
            site: Clean($("#txtSite").val()),
            splunk_class: Clean($("#txtSplunkClass").val()),
            subclass: Clean($("#txtSubclass").val()),
            status: Clean($("#txtStatus").val()),
            platform: Clean($("#txtPlatform").val()),
            spec: Clean($("#txtSpec").val()),
            comments: Clean($("#txtComments").val()),
            record_id: Clean($("#txtRecordID").val()),
            action: "Add/Update",
            page_name:location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        } ;
        console.log(postdata);

        //New Validation
        var validated = true;
        var msg = "One or more fields do not meet the validation requirements:<ul>";
        var fields_names = {"splunk_host": "Splunk Host", "ip": "IP Address", "mgmt_ip": "Management IP", "splunk_role": "Role", "environment": "Environment", "site": "Site", "splunk_class": "Splunk Class", "subclass": "Subclass", "status": "Status", "platform": "Platform", "spec": "Spec", "comments": "Comments", "record_id": "Record ID"};
        var required_fields = ["splunk_host", "ip", "mgmt_ip", "splunk_role", "environment", "site", "splunk_class", "subclass", "status", "platform", "spec"];
        var field_to_html_id = {"splunk_host": "txtSplunkHost", "ip": "txtIP", "mgmt_ip": "txtMgmtIP", "splunk_role": "txtRole", "environment": "txtEnvironment", "site": "txtSite", "splunk_class": "txtSplunkClass", "subclass": "txtSubclass", "status": "txtStatus", "platform": "txtPlatform", "spec": "txtSpec"};
        var field_lengths = {"splunk_host": 255, "ip": 25, "mgmt_ip": 50, "splunk_role": 100, "environment": 25, "site": 100, "splunk_class": 100, "subclass": 100, "status": 25, "platform": 100, "spec": 100, "comments": 1000, "record_id": 100};
        $.each(required_fields, function(i,l) {
            var field = required_fields[i];
            var field_id = "#" + field_to_html_id[l];
            console.log(field_id);
            if ( postdata[field] === "" ) {
                msg = msg + "<li>" + fields_names[l] + " is required</li>";
                validated = false;
                console.log(fields_names[l] + " is blank");
                $(field_id).addClass("error");
                $(field_id + "_label").addClass("error");
            }
            else {
                //console.log(fields_names[l] + " is not blank");
            }
        });
        $.each(field_lengths, function(k,v) {
            var field = k;
            var length_limit = v;
            var field_id = "#" + field_to_html_id[k];
            if ( postdata[field].length > length_limit) {
                msg = msg + "<li>" + fields_names[k] + " is limited to " + String(length_limit) + " characters</li>";
                console.log(fields_names[k] + " is over the character limit of " + String(length_limit));
                validated = false;
                $(field_id).addClass("error");
                $(field_id + "_label").addClass("error");
            }
            else {
                //console.log(fields_names[k] + " is within the character limit");
            }
        });
        if (validated) {
            // submit when validated is true
            $.post( "/submit", {data:JSON.stringify(postdata)},
                function( data ) {
                    var msg = data;
                    console.log(msg);
                    $("#dlgmessage").html(msg);
                    $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
                    if (
                        msg == "Database Update Successful" ||
                        msg == "Database Submission Successful"
                    ) {
                       $(location).attr('href', '/protected/ci_splunk_server_list.html'); 
                    }
                    //return false;
                },
                'text'
            );
        }
        else {
            msg = msg + "</ul>";
            console.log(msg);
            $( "#dlgmessage" ).html(msg);
            $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog("open");
            return;
        }
    });
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     $("#dialog-message").dialog({
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      position: { my: "top", at: "top", of: $("#page-inner") },
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });    
});
```

```css
/*========================================
Errors
========================================*/
.error input {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.error label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label id="txtSplunkHost_label">Splunk Host (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Splunk Host" id="txtSplunkHost" value="" maxlength="255" autofocus="">
 <label id="txtIP_label">IP Address (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="IP Address" id="txtIP" value="" maxlength="25" pattern="^[1-9]\d*$">
 <label id="txtMgmtIP_label">Management IP (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Management IP" id="txtMgmtIP" value="" maxlength="50">
 <label id="txtRole_label">Role (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Role" id="txtRole" value="" maxlength="100">
 <label id="txtEnvironment_label">Environment (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Environment" id="txtEnvironment" value="" maxlength="25">
 <label id="txtSite_label">Site (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Site" id="txtSite" value="" maxlength="100">
 <label id="txtSplunkClass_label">Splunk Class (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Splunk Class" id="txtSplunkClass" value="" maxlength="100">
 <label id="txtSubclass_label">Subclass (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subclass" id="txtSubclass" value="" maxlength="100">
 <label id="txtStatus_label">Status (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Status" id="txtStatus" value="" maxlength="25">
 <label id="txtPlatform_label">Platform (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Platform" id="txtPlatform" value="" maxlength="100">
 <label id="txtSpec_label">Spec (*)</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Spec" id="txtSpec" value="" maxlength="100">
 <label id="txtComments_label">Comments</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" id="txtComments" value="" maxlength="1000">
 <input type="hidden" id="txtRecordID" value="">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: classes are so much nicer..... Select all element with the class and loop to remove.

Comment: OH MY GOD TOO MUCH INFORMATION SCREAMS OUT AT ME

Comment: @TheCodesee sorry? I was trying to be through...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a better implementation,
following is a dynamic approach where you won't need to add hundreds of if conditions and DOM selectors. This approach is also using the recommended `css` approach rather than applying individual style properties.

Code is easy to understand and self explanatory.

```js
$("#submit").on("click", function(e) {

  //Prevent default form action
  e.preventDefault();

  //Add all inputs into an array
  var inputs = [$("#name"), $("#address")],
    is_form_valid = true;

  //Validations
  for (var i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].val() == "") {
      inputs[i].parent().addClass("error");
      inputs[i].focus();
      is_form_valid = false;
      break;
    } else {
      inputs[i].parent().removeClass("error");
    }
  }

  //Form has no validation errors.
  if (is_form_valid) {
    //Do your work here...
    alert("Form submitted");
  }

});
```

```css
.error input[type="text"] {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.error label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form novalidate>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="address">
  </div>

  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**UPDATE**

I see you have done some work to make it more *readable* :)
There are tons of form validation libraries out there. As an advice I would recommand you to use some of them without re-inventing the wheel. But this is good practice for you learn good coding standards.

Your problem is `css` classes are wrong with your `HTML` structure. Those classes were added by me for my `HTML` structure. In your case there is no wrapper `div`. You should directly access `input` and `label` with `error` class as below.

```
/*========================================
Errors
========================================*/
input.error  {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
label.error  {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post with some things I have done to update my code since my original posting. Classes work much better, but the class is being added however the style is not being seen on the page now that I am attempting to add it only to the elements which are invalid.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for, I am still fairly new to css and javascript/jquery so your assistance is much appreciated. It is working exactly as I was looking for, and yeah a standard validation library might have saved me some effort and time and I should look into using one as I move forward